# How to receive TCP IP Message from a remote device in .Net

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am new to socket programming. i need to store the data coming from a remote device.

that device will send data in string format(datapacket format) that to in post method. It will take tcp ip address and port address and submits data to this address.

I need to store that data and do further action(reports).

Now i want to know what is the process i need to follow in order to receive that data. I read some threads we have to use tcp listner to read this.

In this process i created a client which will send some data using following code.

```
string Message=" Tcp Message";
byte[] Buffer=System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Message);
listBox1.Items.Add("Opening Connection");
TcpClient ObjClient = new TcpClient();
ObjClient.Connect("sekharam-PC", 2238);
listBox1.Items.Add( "Connection Success, sending Message");
ObjClient.GetStream().Write(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length);
ObjClient.Close();
```

it is sending but when i change the port number throwing error saying device with ip address is not accepting.

first of all i want to create client and server in my system itself, can you explain whole process that i need to follow to do these type of things.

what port numbers can i use in my system, how to listen incoming data from a remote device, i Want to check it in my local system both client and server.

can you explain the process step by step, i am totally confused.

Answer (score 1):

You have to know the basics of Networking and TCP, Please read the article in the following link

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10649/An-Introduction-to-Socket-Programming-in-NET-using

Answer (score 1):

TCP is a connection based protocol. You can only send data across it, if you have something on the other side willing to accept it.

In .Net this would be a TCPListener class. 
This listens on a specific port, for an incoming connection on that port.

If you don't have the listener, you will get the 'Connection refused, the remote host forcibly rejected.... ' message.

Once you have the listener, it is a case of :

Client.Connect("Hostname",PortNumber);

The Listener then needs to create a corresponding client for the incoming connection. (This facilitates back and forth communication)

```
If(TCPListener.Pending()) // Someone wants to connect to the listener
{
   TCPClient client = TCPListener.Accept();
   //Do stuff with the receiver to receive data  (you need to simulaneously send data on the sender side)


}
```